# How to run linux distributions on android tablets?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, android, tablet

I heard that android uses a linux kernel. Does that mean android tablets can run linux distributions like debian or arch? How can I replace stock android with linux on a tablet?

Answer (score 1):

1. Android uses a patched Linux kernel which includes a ton of firmware and often closed libraries to support/use hardware (touch screen, radio modules, GPS modules, audio, etc.) which means using a standard Linux kernel on it is near impossible.
2. Android uses/offers a vastly different [graphics subsystem](https://source.android.com/docs/core/graphics/surfaceflinger-windowmanager) than Linux distros, so running Linux (X11/Wayland) graphical applications under the Android kernel directly is not possible which means you cannot install a Linux distro on an Android tablet while retaining the Android Linux kernel.
3. You can install Linux distros in a sort of `chroot`and forward graphics using e.g. VNC, or you can even try to install the full-featured [Limbo Emulator](https://virtualmachinery.weebly.com/) where you can actually install a full OS but since it uses emulation, this will be relatively slow and a lot slower if you want to run an x86 OS under an ARM Android device.

You can check an overview of possible ways of installing and using a Linux distro under Android here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-linux-on-android/

You could have better luck asking this question on https://android.stackexchange.com/questions or https://forum.xda-developers.com/